# Is it a good practice to use in package.json '*' instead of a certain version of library of '~', '^'?

Tags: javascript, npm, version, package.json

I passed one learning course on Node.js and Angular. And the teacher there used in
package.json

A lot of asterisks instead of specific versions of libs.

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "*",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "cors": "*",
    "express": "*",
    "jsonwebtoken": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-jwt": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
```

Is it a good or a bad practice to use them?

Comment: No it is not good practice. Why? new upgrade, your code relies on previous version. They change syntax and boom.... your code does not run.

Comment: One or more having breaking changes and its chaos

Answer (score 6):

Wildcard is a bad idea. It says load the latest version no matter what. Sounds like a good idea so you do not have to keep updating. It is great until they introduce breaking changes into the api.

If they update from v1.5 to v2.0 and they changed their api, your code that relies on 1.5 syntax will no longer work in v2.0 if it is not backwards compatible. Do this with multiple packages and you have a huge mess on your hands.

Some people will allow the minor version to be wildcard, but most people lock it down and manually upgrade so it can be fully tested.

https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning